# How i can get the data-price in input field from select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There will also be Product 3, 4, and so on.

The input field name, price, id, class is being populated dynamically from a database so they are the same for different Items.

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
  var productParent = $(this).parent().parent();
  var newPrice = parseFloat(productParent.find('.price').attr('data-price'));
  productParent.find(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
  });
  productParent.find(".price").html("&pound;" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 
 
    <label>Size: </label>
    <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
      <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
      <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
      <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>
 
  <input class="price pull-left form-control " itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
  
 <br>
 <hr>
 
      <label>Size: </label>
      <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
        <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
        <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="price pull-left form-control" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
```

Comment: Why don't you make it a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parent to get value. Use `data` to get value and get your price.

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
  var Parent = $(this).parent(".outer");
  var actualPrice = parseFloat(Parent.find('.price').data('price'));
   actualPrice += parseFloat(Parent.find(".readers option:selected").data('price'));
  Parent.find(".price").val(actualPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- added outer div -->
<div class="outer">
  <label>Size: </label>
  <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
    <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
  </select>

  <input class="price pull-left form-control " itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div class="outer">
  <label>Size: </label>
  <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
    <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
  </select>

  <input class="price pull-left form-control" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give some `outer` div around your select and input then use `.closest()` to get reference of outer div and use this to get other values and set these values in input box using `.val()`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
//get closest outer div
  var productParent = $(this).closest(".outer");
  //get attr from 
  var newPrice = parseFloat(productParent.find('.price').attr('data-price'));
   newPrice += parseFloat(productParent.find(".readers option:selected").attr('data-price'));
//set in input box
  productParent.find(".price").val("£" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- added outer div -->
<div class="outer">
  <label>Size: </label>
  <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
    <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
  </select>

  <input class="price pull-left form-control " itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div class="outer">
  <label>Size: </label>
  <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
    <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
  </select>

  <input class="price pull-left form-control" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
  var productParent = $(this).parent().parent();
  var newPrice = parseFloat(productParent.find('.price').attr('data-price'));
  productParent.find(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
  });
  productParent.find(".price").val("&pound;" + newPrice.toFixed(2)); //change html to val
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 
 
    <label>Size: </label>
    <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
      <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
      <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
      <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>
 
  <input class="price pull-left form-control " itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
  
 <br>
 <hr>
 
      <label>Size: </label>
      <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
        <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
        <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="price pull-left form-control" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">
```

[read here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp) more about `val` function